# Write to file the output of the 2nd command-line argument only

Tags: bash, shell

Using the following command, is there any possibilities to use a `>> myfile.txt` only to write the result of ONE argument not the whole execution? 
i.e: I only want to save in myfile.txt the output of the ran command " +login admin " not the other ones.

```
./core.sh +login admin +usemod tool +exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very unlikely, unless your `core.sh` script knows about how to do such things.  Your best bet is if some of the output is directed to STDOUT, and some to STDERR, you can capture one and ignore the other.  You can also try using the various tools, like `grep, awk, sed, or perl` to filter your output so that only the login related output makes it through, for example:

```
./core.sh +login admin +usemod tool +exit | grep login >> myfile.txt
```